# Deploy Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

My python version is 3.5.2

Django version is 1.8.13

I made a django app and wanna dploy to heroku.

when I type `heroku open`

Then local server display application error.

After googling.

I fixed my wsgi.py but still error.

```
.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting CACHES, but settings are not configured. 
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

"'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set   

"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' environment variable must be set before importing 'whitenoise.django'

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 506, in reap_workers raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)

gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "weather_station.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise 

application = DjangoWhiteNoise(get_wsgi_application())
```

[setting.py](http://codepad.org/bbBStjTz)

[local_setting.py](http://codepad.org/U5wKxTRV)

Is there any key concept i missed?

[**UPDATE**]

procfile

`web: gunicorn weather_station.wsgi --pythonpath weather_station`

Comment: Please show your Procfile.

Answer (score 0):

`heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=weather_station.settings`

this is the manual way

Answer (score 0):

I used this way to set the settings. You can refer this 
[django settings for heroku by django girls](https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/content/heroku/) or best follow the instructions at [heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Here `BASE_DIR` location of `settings` is override by  `BASE_DIR` of `local_settings`. So, Try to Move below lines to very top of your `settings.py`.

```
try: 
    from .local_settings import * 
except ImportError: 
    pass
```

I suggest you to follow the bellow structure to handle setting peacefully for local and live server.

```
settings/
    __init__.py
    base.py
    local.py
    production.py
```

Add common settings for both `local` and `production` in `base.py`

And local.py

```
import * from .base.py
// Other settings required only for local server like 
// Example DEBUG = True
```

production.py

```
import * from .base.py
// Other settings required only for live server
// Example DEBUG = False
```

Point your production settings in `wsgi.py`. So, change

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings.production"
```

To start local server point out local settings while start local server.

```
./manage.py runserver --settings=project_name.settings.local
```

hope this helps.